# Spark unable to parse csv with weird triple quotes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have a csv file with 16 fields, and these two records in particular are unable to be correctly parsed

```
1,"X","X",,"Y ""Y"", Y, Y","Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y",,,,,,"X",,,,"X"
2,"X","X",,"""Y"" Y, Y","Y,Y,Y,Y",,,,,,"X","X",,,"X"
```

Expected deliminators -

```
1|"X"|"X"||"Y ""Y"", Y, Y"|"Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y"||||||"X"||||"X"
2|"X"|"X"|"""Y"" Y, Y"|"Y,Y,Y,Y"||||||"X"|"X"|||"X"
```

Now for example, `"Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y"` this field is being correctly parsed to a single column, but `"""Y"" Y, Y"` and `"Y ""Y"", Y, Y"` are failing.  Is there anyway to correct this when using spark to read from a csv? Some option? I can use?

Note - the incoming data can not be changed in anyway, so escaping double quotes in the landing data is not an option.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138591/2707792) (with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354838/2707792) correction) fully address your problem?

Comment: I see that both the answer and the correction are same. Could you please confirm ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried like below and it’s working

spark.read.format(“csv”).load(“path”).show

Comment: You tried it on what spark version?

Comment: Correct, however, this does not account for actual malformed data.  For example `1|x|2` would load fine into that, but is actually malformed because it's missing columns.  The other anwser provided solved my issue `.option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"")`

Comment: It’s Spark 2.2 version