# PySpark - READ csv file with quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have csv file as below

```
name|age|county|state|country
"alex"john"|"30"|"burlington"|"nj"|"usa"
```

I use spark to read the csv file

```
input_df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='false', sep='|').load('s3://path_to_file')

display(input_df)
```

Output (Not sure why we have quotes around alex"john but not around other fields)

```
name        age county     state    country
"alex"john" 30  burlington  nj      usa
```

Expected output:

```
name        age county     state    country
alex"john   30  burlington  nj      usa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark chooses to read all of name as a string(including all quotes) as the quote in the middle throws it off. Just remove first and last double quotes like this(after reading it):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("name", F.expr("""substring(name,2,length(name)-2)""")).show()

#+---------+---+----------+-----+-------+
#|name     |age|county    |state|country|
#+---------+---+----------+-----+-------+
#|alex"john|30 |burlington|nj   |usa    |
#+---------+---+----------+-----+-------+
```

In order to do in **`dynamically for all columns,`** I would suggest regex like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(*[F.regexp_replace(x,'^\"|\"$','').alias(x) for x in df.columns]).show()

#+---------+---+----------+-----+-------+
#|name     |age|county    |state|country|
#+---------+---+----------+-----+-------+
#|alex"john|30 |burlington|nj   |usa    |
#+---------+---+----------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: In real time, I do not know the column names and this needs to be handled dynamically for all columns.

Comment: Let's say I have input as below. ``` name|age|county|state|country
"alex\"john"|"30"|"burlington"|"nj"|"usa"``` .. How do I use the escape character so I avoid this regex ?

Comment: that should do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413526/reading-csv-files-with-quoted-fields-containing-embedded-commas

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one given that there isn't something escaping that inner quote (like a "\").

If you don't find a way to escape the inner quote, I suggest you read the data as is and trim the surrounding quotes using the regex_replace function like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("tmp.csv")
df.withColumn("formatted_name", regexp_replace(df.name, '^\"|\"$', "")).show()
```

Output:

```sh
+-----------+---+----------+-----+-------+--------------+
|       name|age|    county|state|country|formatted_name|
+-----------+---+----------+-----+-------+--------------+
|"alex"john"| 30|burlington|   nj|    usa|     alex"john|
+-----------+---+----------+-----+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: In real time, I do not know the column names and this needs to be handled dynamically for all columns