# How to write a pyspark dataframe with commas within a field in a csv file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

I have a Pyspark dataframe that has commas in one of the field.
Sample data:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id      |reason                                                                              |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123-8aab|Request for the added "Hello Ruth, How are, you, doing and Other" abc. Thanks!      |
|125-5afs|Hi Prachi, I added an "XYZA", like josa.coam, row. "Uid to be eligible" for clarity.|
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I am writing this in csv, the data is spilling on to the next column and is not represented correctly. Code I am using to write data and output:

```
df_csv.repartition(1).write.format('csv').option("header", "true").save(
        "s3://{}/report-csv".format(bucket_name), mode='overwrite')
```

How data appears in csv:

[image]

Any help would really be appreciated. TIA.

**NOTE** : I think if the field has just commas, its exporting properly, but the combination of quotes and commas is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was-->

```
df_csv.repartition(1).write.format('csv').option("header", "true").option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").save("s3://{}/report-csv".format(bucket_name), mode='overwrite')
```

More detailed explanation in this post:
[Reading csv files with quoted fields containing embedded commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413526/reading-csv-files-with-quoted-fields-containing-embedded-commas)