# Pyspark is not reading csv properly around quote

Tags: csv, pyspark

This line `"{""subject"":""Title"",""Headline"":""test head""}",2021-01-01` should have two column while doing

`spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("multiLine","true").csv('test.csv')`
gives me three columns.

I think the issue is that pyspark does not escape the `"` when it encounters two quotes in a row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading csv files with quoted fields containing embedded commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413526/reading-csv-files-with-quoted-fields-containing-embedded-commas)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138591/19032206. Adding `.option("escape", "\"")` will get you covered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @qaziqarta

Adding `.option("escape", "\"")`